# iOS 16 – Recovery Contact shown as added 1 Jan 1970

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, family-sharing

After upgrading my iPhone SE 2020 to iOS 16.0 (20A362), I went to *Settings > Family > Family Checklist* and saw a prompt to add a recovery contact. After adding a family member they’re now shown as added on 1 January 1970.

A minor issue really, I just wondered if it’s specific to mine or a small number of phones, or a bug affecting everybody in the new iOS.

Comment: 1 Jan 70 is the 'unix epoch' The date unix time started - at a guess that would mean the timestamp was added as 'zero'. [Apple has a placeholder for things without any timestamp, but that date is 24 Jan 1984.]